# Application throws error on Ubuntu 19 with Java 11

Tags: java, ubuntu, kotlin, netty, ktor

Could one please help me figure out the reason why my application written in `Kotlin`fails to run after it was built with `Intellij Idea` and deployed to `Ubuntu 19.10` virtual machine ?

I use the following components:

1. Ktor 1.3.0
2. Netty for Ktor

**Launch logs:**

```
15:22:08.488 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory - Using SLF4J as the default logging framework
15:22:08.530 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - -Dio.netty.noUnsafe: false
15:22:08.530 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - Java version: 11
15:22:08.568 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - sun.misc.Unsafe.theUnsafe: available
15:22:08.569 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - sun.misc.Unsafe.copyMemory: available
15:22:08.569 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.Buffer.address: available
15:22:08.577 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - direct buffer constructor: unavailable
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Reflective setAccessible(true) disabled
        at io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil.trySetAccessible(ReflectionUtil.java:31)
        at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0$4.run(PlatformDependent0.java:225)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0.<clinit>(PlatformDependent0.java:219)
        at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.isAndroid(PlatformDependent.java:273)
        at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.<clinit>(PlatformDependent.java:92)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.loadNativeLibrary(Native.java:225)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:57)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Epoll.<clinit>(Epoll.java:39)
        at io.ktor.server.netty.EventLoopGroupProxy$Companion.create(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:189)
        at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationEngine.<init>(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:74)
        at io.ktor.server.netty.Netty.create(Embedded.kt:14)
        at io.ktor.server.netty.Netty.create(Embedded.kt:12)
        at io.ktor.server.engine.EmbeddedServerKt.embeddedServer(EmbeddedServer.kt:79)
        at io.ktor.server.engine.EmbeddedServerKt.embeddedServer$default(EmbeddedServer.kt:77)
        at app.common.ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt:96)
15:22:08.581 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.Bits.unaligned: available, true
15:22:08.582 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.allocateUninitializedArray(int): unavailable
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0$6 cannot access class jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export jdk.internal.misc to unnamed module @6d3af739
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:361)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:591)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:558)
        at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0$6.run(PlatformDependent0.java:335)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0.<clinit>(PlatformDependent0.java:326)
        at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.isAndroid(PlatformDependent.java:273)
        at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.<clinit>(PlatformDependent.java:92)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.loadNativeLibrary(Native.java:225)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:57)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Epoll.<clinit>(Epoll.java:39)
        at io.ktor.server.netty.EventLoopGroupProxy$Companion.create(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:189)
        at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationEngine.<init>(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:74)
        at io.ktor.server.netty.Netty.create(Embedded.kt:14)
        at io.ktor.server.netty.Netty.create(Embedded.kt:12)
        at io.ktor.server.engine.EmbeddedServerKt.embeddedServer(EmbeddedServer.kt:79)
        at io.ktor.server.engine.EmbeddedServerKt.embeddedServer$default(EmbeddedServer.kt:77)
        at app.common.ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt:96)
15:22:08.586 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(long, int): unavailable
15:22:08.587 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - sun.misc.Unsafe: available
15:22:08.710 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - maxDirectMemory: 249364480 bytes (maybe)
15:22:08.711 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.tmpdir: /tmp (java.io.tmpdir)
15:22:08.711 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.bitMode: 64 (sun.arch.data.model)
15:22:08.713 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.maxDirectMemory: -1 bytes
15:22:08.713 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.uninitializedArrayAllocationThreshold: -1
15:22:08.714 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.CleanerJava9 - java.nio.ByteBuffer.cleaner(): available
15:22:08.714 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.noPreferDirect: false
15:22:08.716 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader - -Dio.netty.native.workdir: /tmp (io.netty.tmpdir)
15:22:08.717 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader - -Dio.netty.native.deleteLibAfterLoading: true
15:22:08.717 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader - -Dio.netty.native.tryPatchShadedId: true
15:22:08.718 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader - Unable to load the library 'netty_transport_native_epoll_x86_64', trying other loading mechanism.
```

Comment: `because module java.base does not export jdk.internal.misc to unnamed module`
try to follow the logs (error trace). If you locate real problem then, please rewrite question to be more precise.

Comment: Improved the question grammar